# How to install Laravel in subdomain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, subdomain

I have my site: http://www.markdev.com.br

, where the there is a subdomain (maestro.markdev.com.br) and there is an app for laravel that is in (public_html / subdomains / conductor).

How do I do to run laravel normally when accessing the subdomain or path without getting error 500?

I appreciate all the attention

Comment: the correct directory is public_html /subdomains/maestro

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special to install Laravel in a sub-domain as Laravel won't know either way - you just need to install it correctly and configure the sub-domain on your web server.

So inside your `public_html/subdomains/conductor` directory you can install your Laravel project. Make sure that you run `composer install` to install all of the files and dependencies, and then set the folder permissions of `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` correctly.

On your web-server end, set up a vhost to direct the request to the correct directory:

`public_html/subdomains/conductor`

Or link it to the public directory to prevent users having to type in `maestro.markdev.com.br/public`:

`public_html/subdomains/conductor/public`